# How to apply jquery client side validation

Tags: jquery, struts2, client-side-validation

Below is the code I am using to submit a form.  The problem is that I am not able to apply the jquery client validation.  Please help me with the necessary jquery to do the same.  Thanks in advance

```
<s:form name="add" method="post" id="formId" theme="simple">
    <s:textfield name="server.title" cssClass="input_text_lrg" id="Title"/>
    <s:textfield name="server.name" cssClass="input_text" id="Name"/>
    <s:url id="SAVE_ADD" action="save" namespace="/"/>
    <sj:submit name="submit" value="Save" cssClass="input_button" labelposition="left" href="% {SAVE_ADD}" targets="results" />
</s:form>
```

Comment: Have you tried any validation so far? If yes, kindly share the code. If not, I recommend that you use $.submit() event where you can place the validation code. Also, there are few jQuery validation plugins that you may look at, such as... http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: what you have tried so far and where exactly you facing the issue? SO is a place where people can help you to solve you issue/problem,expecting a code from community is least expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for jquery client side validation, i suggest you visit [this site](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). The process is pretty straightforward.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $.subscribe('validateFields', function(event,data) {
 $("#formId").validate();});{);
<sj:submit name="submit" value="Save and Add" cssClass="input_button" labelposition="left" href="%{SAVE_ADD}" targets="rightContainer" onBeforeTopics="validateFields"/>I had made this change then also not working

Comment: @subbusaabu did you add `class="required"` to your fields. In your own case, you can do this: `cssClass="input_text required"` You can see an example here. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: i used the same (cssClass="input_text required") but its showing error as jquery not found

Comment: @subbusaabu do you have jQuery library in your page. Note it needs to be declared before the validation library. Can you post your completed page, this will help me to assist you.